# UIDocumentPickerViewController and Dropbox import error 11004

Tags: ios, dropbox, file-sharing, uidocumentpickervc

I have interesting problem. I am using UIDocumentPickerViewController. And in list can to choose Dropbox:

[image]

When i select on one of file sime time I get error: (dropbox.com error -11004). And I understend that it is not my allert whis is allert from dropbox application.

[image]

Please help to understand the problem and how it can be solved?
What does this error mean?
Maybe someone decided it somehow?

Any ideas may be helpful. Thank you!